# tSQL how to write a view/function which returns a table of dynamic size

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, dynamic

I have recently written a script in t-SQL which uses dynamic SQL to generate a table. The output of the script varies, depending on when it is run. The output is something like this:

```
Group   2010    2011   2012   2013
  A      1       2       3      2
  B      4       3       3      4
  C      4       3       1      1
```

However, each year another year is added onto the table, meaning the table size varies.

e.g.

```
Group   2010    2011   2012   2013   2014
  A      1       2       3      2     2
  B      4       3       3      4     2
  C      4       3       1      1     3
```

I need to be able to access the data in this table via access to generate some reports, so require some sort of view or function to get the data.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

if you have to use this output in report. Than you have to fix column name in SQL as below.

```
Group  year4    year3    year2   year1
  A      1       2        3       2
  B      4       3        3       4
  C      4       3        1       1
```

and in report tools you can convert year1 = current year, year2 = current year - 1 and so on.

update 2

using this method you can easily design your report.

```
Group   year5  year4   year3   year2   year1
  A      1       2       3       2      2
  B      4       3       3       4      2
  C      4       3       1       1      3
```

Comment: Thanks the reply! I would probably use this, but I need a full list of years from year x to the current year, meaning a variable table size. I have decided to solve this by making the code into a stored procedure and then dropping and regenerating a table from this once a day (the data I'm dealing with doesn't change very often, so not a big deal).

Comment: if you are using crystal report than you can use cross tab report also.